# How to enable control character (e.g. carriage return) handling in emacs shell

Tags: shell, term

I run compilation processes that, in a terminal, list what was built all on the same line. In emacs shell they are all on separate lines, filling my shell buffer with unwanted output. I realize I could run the terminal emulator in emacs, but there are lots of reasons why I prefer to use emacs shell. If I could get emacs shell to handle the control sequences correctly (that is, in this case, handle \r by going to the beginning of the same line and erase the line on further output) that would be fantastic.

Any idea if this is possible?

Comment: That kind of thing might get easier if the Emacs developers ever get to combining term and shell (as indicated in one of the FIXME comments)...

Comment: Yes, that would be so great if they did that.

Comment: I'm less sure about that as they serve different purposes.  One seeks to emulate a terminal (and is sluggish), the other controls REPLs (and is fast).